# Is there a way to create a generic Electron application with electron-builder to build multiple Ember.js projects with independent versioning?

Tags: ember.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I'm looking for a way to automate the electron builds for EmberJs build projects.

I have a pipeline where I would clone the built EmberJs-project in a specific folder in an Electron project which then uses electron-builder to generate an installer for this project.

I need to keep this electron-project generic but the usage of the package.json version for the builds and auto-updater is preventing this. Is there a way to select the Ember project version / tag for builds instead of the one specified in the electron project?

Or is there another way to add/check versions of electron builds?

I really wan't to prevent forking my base electron-project for every new EmberJs-project.

I tried adding a package.json-file in the folder where I clone my built project and specify a version there but this seems to override my electron-project package.json-file which I would like to keep using for the generic scripts and links.

in my electron package.json:

```
"name": "electron-launcher",
"version": "0.1.0", => needs to be independant of the builds if possible
"scripts": {
    "dist": "electron-builder -p always"
  },
...
```

My project structure

- package.json (electron)
- main.js
- resources (folder containing EmberJS dist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, I found out that setting up a different branch for every project with it's own package.json file was the best solution for me, adding a checkout and a version increment in my pipeline gave me the control i needed.

This might not be the best solution out there but it works in my case.